# How I can build a custom/dynamic uploading form in Django 2.1 so that the user can upload the data within the required elements

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

I am building an app in Django 2.1 which allows users to upload posts. I have achieved this using Django forms and sent the data back to DB (this is simple as it has post title and the post itself). Now I want to enhance this with the dynamic generation of elements while user uploads the data i.e. how can I implement the following requirement :

1. How can we allow users to add unknown number of images while uploading a post OR for a technical post user wants to add code snippets (dynamic number of snippets anywhere in the post). The post should be saved in the DB and then will be rendered.
2. How would the DB schema be defined in this scenario, because the number of elements are undefined initially.

Take a simple example to understand the requirement: Start writing a post on blogger and there would be n number of UI elements available to add in the post at the runtime.

I have got a reference while googling:
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/

I'm a newbie and want to know how I can technically achieve this. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How would the DB schema be defined in this scenario, because the number of elements are undefined initially.

This is the purpose of *relations* in a *Relational database*.

When an object `Core` contains/is related to multiple objects `Extension`, we call that relation a *One To Many relationship* (as One `Core` possesses/has Many `Extensions`).

In SQL, and also in Django, those OneToMany are represented by [Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

So in your case, you'll do it with something like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=xxx)
    content = models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(...)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Snippet(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

> How can we allow users to add unknown number of images while uploading a post OR for a technical post user wants to add code snippets (dynamic number of snippets anywhere in the post).

For your frontend, you can use the [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/) which can be used in your case (as you have multiple input corresponding to the same Model).

With some little *javascript*, you can use the [Django empty_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form) to dynamically display a new form when your end user fills the one already displayed, for example.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Basically I wanted to ask about a rich text formatter/editor ribbon kind of thing (like we do in MS-Word) so that it gives the liberty to the user to style the parts of the post wherever is required without even using ForeignKey and a single textarea will do the job.

Comment: Oh ok, so for the backend, you can simply use a `TextField` and you will encode/decode your formatting and images (base64 for images?) and for the frontend, a lot of editor js libraries exists like for instance https://codex.so/editor (but I'm not in that stuff, so I cannot really advise you :/ )

Comment: I really don't know at the moment for the media stuff but will do it and keep you posted. Embedding media into the post is not the requirement as of now but priority is to make the text area rich so that at least text marking, formatting etc. can be done. Thanks.